# How do you change the keyboard layout from QWERTY in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-layout

I typically use Workman as my default keyboard layout, but this causes issues with VSCode as it does not detect the change. What this means is that all the keybinds in VSCode are all over the place; the keybinds in VSCode don't adjust to match the current keyboard layout. This especially causes issues for extensions such as the Vim extension for VSCode which, obviously, relies **heavily**  on keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Is this on Linux?

Comment: @Martheen Yes it is.

Comment: Possibly https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103339